# What do I need to change to have a fully transparent panel?

Tags: gnome, theme

I have a theme which sets the background of my panel to a certain color, even when I tell it to be transparent via the panel properties.

[image]

In the theme's gtkrc file, what do I need to change to set the background color to be trasparent? I haven't written my own themes before, so I'm kind of lost. Another theme I have does it right, but since I don't know how to read the theme file, I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly, GNOME doesn't handle transparency correctly if the background is a pixmap. It is possible that the theme you are using uses a pixmap to fill the background, and as such it is not working as you expect.

If this is the issue, the solution to such a problem would be to comment out any instances of `bg_pixmap` in your `.gtkrc`, and then restart the panel. `ed` or `ex` can do this for you like so:

```
ed -s .gtkrc << EOF
g/^bg_pixmap/s//#bg_pixmap/g
w
q
EOF

pkill '^gnome-panel'
```

I'm not running GNOME, so I can't test this, but it should work.

Comment: YES! THANK YOU SO MUCH. As it turns out, the theme I wished to edit was Shiki-Wise, so I opened `/usr/share/themes/Shiki-Wise/gtk-2.0/panel.rc` and commented out the line: `bg_pixmap[NORMAL] = "/Panels/panel-bg-dark.png"`. Thanks again!